# Cannot find an overload for SequenceEqual exception from Powershell script when run from a different machine

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a simple powershell script which contains the below code  :

```
    function newfunction()
  {

    $myArray1 = 1,2,"Hello World"
    $myArray2 = 1,2,"Hello World"
    $something = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual($myArray1,$myArray2)
}
cls
newfunction
```

It works perfectly on my machine but when ran from another it throws me an exception.

I have 4.0 in my machine and also silverlight. The other machine has 4.5. I looked at msdn website and looks like they havent made any changes to this method recently. Has anyone else faced the same issue ?

Comment: Give us what is returned when you type `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual` on remote machine.

Comment: Cannot find an overload for "SequenceEqual" and the argument count : "2". FullQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFIndBest. Thsi si the exception I get.

Comment: Thats not what I asked.

Comment: @ShalimaSidhik What is the "ClrVersion" you ask for `$PSVersionTable` on the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same exception:

```
Cannot find an overload for "SequenceEqual" and the argument count : "2". 
...
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

This exception causes when two arguments are different type, so you may fix with explicit type casting.

```
$something = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual([object[]]$myArray1, [object[]]$myArray2)
```